# Embedded Transaction management JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I have these two classes:

```
public class A {
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true, value="transactionManager")
   public void methodA() {
      B.methodB();
   }
}
```

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor=Exception.class,  noRollbackFor = MyCustomCheckedException.class, value="transactionManager")
public class B {
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true, value="transactionManager")
   public void methodB() throws MyCustomCheckedException {
       try {
       } catch ( AnotherException ex ) {
          throw new MyCustomCheckedException(ex.getCode(), ex.getMessage(), ex);
       }
   }
}
```

MyCustomCheckedException is raised in B.methodB().

In the inner Transaction I am not expecting rollback , but I get an exception after all A.methodA() is executed

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162) ~[cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:267) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128) ~[cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74) ~[cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126) ~[cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) ~[cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131) ~[cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:309) ~[cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:189) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:303) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) [servlet-api.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:278) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.jasypt.web.pbeconfig.WebPBEConfigFilter.doFilter(WebPBEConfigFilter.java:68) [jasypt-1.9.2.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445) [catalina.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1139) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.88]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.88]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.88]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at com.wandrian.vagabond.ws.booking.impl.BookingServicesEndpointImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7adde343.redeliverValueDocumentRequest() ~[classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) ~[cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.performInvocation(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.16.jar:3.1.16]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the transaction starts on `methodA()` call and all the `@Transactional` inside the call hierarchy are ignored. The transaction changes only if one of the inner `@Transactional` has `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` which creates new transaction irrespective of an existing transaction.

The `methodA()`, where the transaction starts, doesn't have `noRollBackFor`, hence you see the error.

From javadoc on `Propagation.REQUIRED`

```
/**
 * Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.
 * Analogous to EJB transaction attribute of the same name.
 * <p>This is the default setting of a transaction annotation.
 */
REQUIRED(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED)
```

There are a few other propagation types also, which can alter the ongoing transaction e.g `NOT_SUPPORTED` which suspends the ongoing transaction.

Comment: OK . Thanks for the answer. I understand Spring will do rollBacks in case of Runtime exceptions. In this case , I am raising a Checked Exception, Why does the rollBack happen if that is not the default behaviour ?

Comment: what does the declaration of `MyCustomCheckedException` looks like?

Comment: You definitely need to use REQUIRES_NEW to get a new transaction for this method (note that it will not participate in the parent transaction).  Also, I don't believe that exception is checked, as I don't see throws MyCustomCheckedException in your method declaration, indicating that it's unchecked.  Regardless of how it's configured, the exception must be checked so it needs to extend either extend Exception or Throwable.

Comment: Sorry My bad, I just did not copy the exact code because I cannot disclose it. But it has the throws declaration                                                                            ```public class MyCustomCheckedException extends Exception {                              }```

Comment: from the javadoc `By default, a transaction will be rolling back on {@link RuntimeException}
  * and {@link Error} but not on checked exceptions (business exceptions)`.  if your custom exception extends `RuntimeException` the transaction won't be rolled back by default.